# Angular5, " | async" pipe is not working, the value from Auth Service is not update in the nav bar

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe, navbar

AuthService go as below, The update in the auth service should actually be updated in the navbar component but I am missing something, there is no error being printed in the log. need help to find the issue

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {  Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
private isLoginSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.hasToken());

constructor(private router: Router) { }
isAuthenticated() {
    return this.hasToken();
}

get isLoggedIn(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoginSubject.asObservable();
  }
login(data): void {
    this.isLoginSubject.next(true);
    localStorage.setItem('blogUser', JSON.stringify(data));
    this.router.navigate(['/admin']);

}
private hasToken(): boolean {
    console.log('has', localStorage.getItem('blogUser'));
    return !!localStorage.getItem('blogUser');
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.isLoginSubject.next(false);
    localStorage.removeItem('blogUser');
    this.router.navigate(['/authentication/login']);
  }
```

}

NavBar component as below:

```
      @Component({
    selector: 'app-nav-bar',
    templateUrl: './nav-bar.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./nav-bar.component.css']
  })
  export class NavBarComponent implements OnInit {
    isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;
  private user;
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
      this.isLoggedIn$ = this.authService.isLoggedIn;
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

  }
```

Nav HTML as below:

```
<nav  *ngIf="isLoggedIn$ | async as isLoggedIn">
<a class="p-2 text-dark" *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn | async )" [routerLink]="['/authentication']">Login</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" *ngIf="!(isLoggedIn | async)" [routerLink]="['/authentication/signup']">Sign up</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-primary" *ngIf="(isLoggedIn | async)"[routerLink]="['/authentication/logout']" >Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `| async` when you are using the `isLoggedIn` variable. The actual value from the observable is bound to that value. It is not an observable itself. Here is a [blog post](https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe) that can offer some more insights on the use of the `| async as` syntax.